# Как работать в JQuery с полученными данными JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Это вопрос скорее все к знатокам JQuery.

Есть у меня такая таблица во view

```
 @foreach (var items in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="AssignButtonClicked(this)"
                           data-assigned-id="@items.ADUsersId" /> 
                </th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.DisplayName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Company)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Department)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.TelephoneNumber)</th>

            </tr>
        }
```

В первом столбе я передаю Id в функцию

```
 function AssignButtonClicked(elem) {
            var id = $(elem).data('assigned-id');
            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Users")',
                type: 'post',
                //cache: false,
                //async: true,
                //data: { id: id }
                data: { id:id }, // OR data: {id:1} => nothing work
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('error');
                }

            })

            };
```

Все отлично работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По клику я получаю данные JSON. Ну вот вопрос, как мне эти данные вывести в раскрывающий список таблицы использую Datatables? Вот здесь есть пример [Пример работы](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Может кому-нибудь понадобиться

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function format(data) {
            var html = '<table class ="table table-hover"">';

                html += '<thead>' + '<tr>' +
                           '<th>' + '<b>' + 'Должность' + '<b>' + '</th>' +
                           '<th>' + '<b>' + 'Мобильный' + '<b>' + '</th>' +
                           '<th>' + '<b>' + 'Почта' + '<b>' + '</th>' +
                           '<th>' + '<b>' + 'Логин' + '<b>' + '</th>' +
                           '<th>' + '<b>' + 'Вход' + '<b>' + '</th>' +
                           '</tr>' + '</thead>' +
                           '<tr>' +
                           '<td>' + data.Title + '</td>' +
                           '<td>' + data.Mobile + '</td>' +
                           '<td>' + data.Mail + '</td>' +
                           '<td>' + data.SAMAccountName + '</td>' +
                           '<td>' + data.LastLogon + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';

            return html += '</table>';
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#UsersTable').DataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Russian.json" },
            });
            $('#UsersTable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var td = $(this);
                var row = table.row(this);
                var id = $(this).attr('data-assigned-id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Users")',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { id: id },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (row.child.isShown()) {
                            row.child.hide();
                            td.removeClass('shown');
                        } else {

                            row.child(format(data)).show();
                            td.addClass('shown');
                        }
                    }, 
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Теперь работает все как надо!
Пример работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чем смысл цикла `for` в функции`format`?

Comment: Я не силен в JavaScript. Как я понимаю можно было While сделать?

Comment: Нет, там вообще цикл не нужен, объект же один.

Comment: Спасибо. Я ковырял зхаработало и поэтому не трогал)) Спасибо!!!